# How to make dynamic background image on a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have no idea if you need to use a dependency, but I use Jquery with ruby on rails. Onto the point though, I have 3 image that I want to use for my background.

A top image, a middle image and a bottom image. I want the top and bottom image to stay static, but have the middle image tile depending how much content is in that page. Anyone have any ideas how one would do this? I've been looking around for awhile with no luck.

```
.background-top {
  background-image: image-url('background/background_top.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: top;
}
.background-mid {
  background-image: image-url('background/background_mid.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
}
.background-bot {
  background-image: image-url('background/background_bot.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some code to see what you currently have?

Comment: Is there any image showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var body = document.body;
html = document.documentElement;
var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
```

USe this code to get height of your page. And add if condition on loading of middle image if height is greater that particular size.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually pretty helpful. I'll see what I can do with this